# Maven "mvn package" issue with a new PHP project

Tags: php, maven, project, package

I'm having some troubles with a new PHP Maven project when trying to run mvn package command.

I've tried to replace "http://repos.xworlds.org" url for "http://repo1.php-maven.org" in settings.xml file, but nothing happens.

Any idea about what could be wrong...?

```
c:\Users\Develop\adc>mvn package -e
+ Error stacktraces are turned on.
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Sample PHP 5 web project
[INFO]    task-segment: [package]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [php:set-sources {execution: default-set-sources}]
[INFO] [plugin:descriptor {execution: default-descriptor}]
[INFO] [resources:resources {execution: default-resources}]
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory c:\Users\Develop\adc\src\main\resources
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Internal error in the plugin manager executing goal 'org.phpmaven:maven-php-plugin:2.0-SNAPSHOT:resourc
es': Unable to load the mojo 'org.phpmaven:maven-php-plugin:2.0-SNAPSHOT:resources' in the plugin 'org.phpmave
n:maven-php-plugin'. A required class is missing: Lorg/apache/maven/project/ProjectBuilder;
org.apache.maven.project.ProjectBuilder
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Trace
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Internal error in the plugin manager executing goal 'o
rg.phpmaven:maven-php-plugin:2.0-SNAPSHOT:resources': Unable to load the mojo 'org.phpmaven:maven-php-plugin:2
.0-SNAPSHOT:resources' in the plugin 'org.phpmaven:maven-php-plugin'. A required class is missing: Lorg/apache
/maven/project/ProjectBuilder;
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:698)

        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalWithLifecycle(DefaultLifecycleExecut
or.java:556)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:535)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalAndHandleFailures(DefaultLifecycleEx
ecutor.java:387)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.ja
va:348)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.execute(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:180)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:328)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:138)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:362)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.compat.CompatibleMain.main(CompatibleMain.java:60)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:315)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:255)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:430)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:375)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginManagerException: Unable to load the mojo 'org.phpmaven:maven-php-plu
gin:2.0-SNAPSHOT:resources' in the plugin 'org.phpmaven:maven-php-plugin'. A required class is missing: Lorg/a
pache/maven/project/ProjectBuilder;
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.getConfiguredMojo(DefaultPluginManager.java:679)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultPluginManager.java:468)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:694)

        ... 17 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lorg/apache/maven/project/ProjectBuilder;
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2291)
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredField(Class.java:1880)
        at hidden.org.codehaus.plexus.util.ReflectionUtils.getFieldByNameIncludingSuperclasses(ReflectionUtils
.java:47)
        at hidden.org.codehaus.plexus.util.ReflectionUtils.getFieldByNameIncludingSuperclasses(ReflectionUtils
.java:55)
        at hidden.org.codehaus.plexus.util.ReflectionUtils.getFieldByNameIncludingSuperclasses(ReflectionUtils
.java:55)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.component.composition.FieldComponentComposer.getFieldByName(FieldComponentCompo
ser.java:212)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.component.composition.FieldComponentComposer.findMatchingField(FieldComponentCo
mposer.java:171)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.component.composition.FieldComponentComposer.assembleComponent(FieldComponentCo
mposer.java:62)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.component.composition.DefaultComponentComposerManager.assembleComponent(Default
ComponentComposerManager.java:68)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.composeComponent(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:1486)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.personality.plexus.lifecycle.phase.CompositionPhase.execute(CompositionPhase.ja
va:29)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleHandler.start(AbstractLifecycleHandler.java:101)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.component.manager.AbstractComponentManager.startComponentLifecycle(AbstractComp
onentManager.java:105)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.component.manager.AbstractComponentManager.createComponentInstance(AbstractComp
onentManager.java:95)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.component.manager.PerLookupComponentManager.getComponent(PerLookupComponentMana
ger.java:48)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:331)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:440)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.getConfiguredMojo(DefaultPluginManager.java:652)
        ... 19 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.maven.project.ProjectBuilder
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.RealmClassLoader.loadClassDirect(RealmClassLoader.java:195)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.DefaultClassRealm.loadClass(DefaultClassRealm.java:255)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.DefaultClassRealm.loadClass(DefaultClassRealm.java:274)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.RealmClassLoader.loadClass(RealmClassLoader.java:214)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
        ... 38 more
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 6 seconds
[INFO] Finished at: Sun Feb 12 16:40:25 ART 2012
[INFO] Final Memory: 23M/324M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maven-php-plugin depends on maven-plugin-api v3.0.3. Make sure you have Maven 3 installed.